Open GLを使用したプログラムについて
以下のプログラムを実行すると、このような側面が長い１２角形が表示されますが、
図形をウィンドウの中央に移動させる、そしてこの図形を小さく見せる方法はわかるかたいれば教えていただきたいです。
図形の描画にあまり理解が追い付いていなくて。
現状の実行結果:

期待する実行結果:
目標は初期設定でこのような１２角錐を表示させることです。

現状のコード:
#include "glut.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <math.h>
#define M_PI 3.14

// プロトタイプ宣言
void display();
void KeyboardHandler(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void TimerFunction(int value);

int isAnimating = 0;  // アニメーションフラグ
double angle = 0.0;   // 回転角度
// タイマーイベントハンドラ
void TimerFunction(int value) {
    if (isAnimating) {
        angle += 24.0 / 60.0; // 1秒間に24度回転 => 1分間に4回転
        if (angle >= 360.0) {
            angle -= 360.0;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, TimerFunction, 0); // 次のタイマーイベント
    }
}
// 12角柱の描画関数
void drawPrism() {
    int N = 12; // 12角柱
    double R = 1.0; // 半径
    double H = 2.0; // 高さ

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // 上面
    glNormal3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        double theta = 2.0 * M_PI * i / N;
        glVertex3d(R * cos(theta), H / 2, R * sin(theta));
    }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // 下面
    glNormal3d(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        double theta = 2.0 * M_PI * i / N;
        glVertex3d(R * cos(theta), -H / 2, R * sin(theta));
    }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP); // 側面
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
        double theta = 2.0 * M_PI * i / N;
        double x = R * cos(theta);
        double z = R * sin(theta);
        glNormal3d(cos(theta), 0.0, sin(theta));
        glVertex3d(x, H / 2, z);
        glVertex3d(x, -H / 2, z);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

// ペイントハンドラ
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotated(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    drawPrism();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// キーボードハンドラ
void KeyboardHandler(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == ' ') {
        isAnimating = !isAnimating;
        if (isAnimating) {
            glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, TimerFunction, 0); // 60 FPS
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("電22-1 芥川 凜太朗");
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 1.0, 1.0, 20.0);
    gluLookAt(4, 4, 0, 0, 0, -8, 0, 1, 0);

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    float light_position[] = { 5.0, 10.0, 2.0, 0.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyboardHandler);
    glutMainLoop();
}



図形をウィンドウの中央に移動させる

【採る方法次第では｛視点，図形，光源｝の相対位置関係が変わるから，ライティングの結果が変化し得る】みたいな話をとりあえず度外視して良いのであれば，
とりあえず最も考えやすいのは，「図形の中心」と「見ている位置」を合わせることだと思う．

gluLookAt() での「着目点」的なパラメタを drawPrism() で描画している図形の中心座標（(0,0,0)かな？）にする
drawPrism() 呼び出しの直前に適切な平行移動変換（ glTranslated() とか）を追加する

みたいな．

この図形を小さく見せる

これはもう適当にスケーリングすればよいだけなのではないでしょうか．

glScaled() あたりを drawPrism() の呼び出し前に加えてやればよいのでは．
なんだったらもう，何も考えずに drawPrism() 内の各値を小さくしてやれば相応にサイズが変わるんじゃないですか？　という気がするのですが．
gluPerspective() で用いている「画角」を変えるという手もある．


……というわけで，例えば
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslated( 0,0, -8 );  //平行移動．（値が間違ってたら適当に直して）
    glRotated(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    glScaled( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 );  //スケーリング．値は適当に調整されたし

    drawPrism();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

的なことをすればよいのではないかと．
（上記のコードは実際に動かしてみたわけじゃないので，パラメタ等は動作を見て適当に調整してください）
最終的に表示されているのは多段階の計算の結果なので，やり方は一つではない（どの段で何をやるか？という自由度がある）ハズなので，最も分かり易い方法でやればよいのではないかと．
